# Loading external page content in specific division

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to display the external page contents in specific divisions. I have found some solutions like iframes etc but nothing helps me much.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Account Details</a>
    </li>
    <li>    
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Wish List</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Edit ACCOUNT</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        ## I WANT CONTENT OF "/MTSITE/PAGE" ##
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        ## I WANT CONTENT OF "/MTSITE/PAGE1" ##
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        ## I WANT CONTENT OF "/MTSITE/PAGE2" ##
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ - assuming that the site allows external requests.

Comment: page is loading but with header and footer :(

Answer (score 0):

Approach for your html based on Rorys' comment:

```
$("#home" ).load("/MTSITE/PAGE", function() {
    console.log("Loaded content for home.");
});

$( "#menu1" ).load("/MTSITE/PAGE1", function() {
    console.log("Loaded content for menu1.");
});

$("#menu2" ).load("/MTSITE/PAGE2", function() {
    console.log("Loaded content for menu2.");
});
```

If you don't want a log in your console, you can use:

```
$("#menu2" ).load("/MTSITE/PAGE2");
```

Comment: when i tried to add the page whole header and footer is coming  :(

Answer (score 0):

you can do like these way using ajax.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eua98tqa/10/

HTML :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="active">
    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Account Details</a>
</li>
<li>    
    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Wish List</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Edit ACCOUNT</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">

</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        ## I WANT CONTENT OF "/MTSITE/PAGE1" ##
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    ## I WANT CONTENT OF "/MTSITE/PAGE2" ##
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$.get('Your URL')
.fail(function(xhr, err){
 $('#home').append("No data");
})
.then(function(responseData) {
  //responseData is the contents of the other page. Do whatever you want with it.
  $('#home').append(responseData);
});
```

Comment: when i tried to add the page whole header and footer is coming :(